# Wrong type argument:/var/lib/gems/2\.5\.0

Tags: linux, debugging, emacs, rubygems, evernote

I want to install a Emacs package "evernote-mode" and there is a step in the installation of the package which needs to run command `gem install evernote_oauth` in shell. If I run the command I get the error message:

```
let: Wrong type argument: listp, /var/lib/gems/2\.5\.0/gems/evernote-thrift-1\.25\.2/lib/thrift/protocol/base_protocol\.rb:254:
```

There are `\` and `/` in the directory of reliable package "evernote_oauth". If I remove the needed package "evernote_oauth" or not to run command `gem install evernote_oauth`, there is an error message

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- evernote_oauth (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/enclient.rb:44:in `<main>'
```

so I guess the reason of the error is relevant to the command `gem install evernote_oauth`. Maybe there is something wrong in the process of using gem to install package `evernote_oauth` in Linux which caused the directory mistake (both `\` and `/` in the directory). But I have no idea how to solve it.
PS：Thanks all the people help me include the person help edit the question,I am a rookie in stackoverflow,I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full commands you are running as well as the full error messages (including the full stack trace if available)

Comment: Post more of the backtrace. You removed the part that tells you just what function was expecting a list argument (type predicate `listp`) but was passed a non-list.

Comment: Thanks Holger and Drew,I have increased the information!Hope it can help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The evernote-mode package is no longer maintained. See [issue #38](https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode/issues/38#issuecomment-1431856227).